# Probability and Variance--Bernoulli, Binomial, Negative Binomial

Tags: probability, negative-binomial

I am taking a course in probability and I have trouble computing the variance of a random variable.

There are 2 cases we saw in class that I would like to understand:

First I will state the definition of variance of expected value:

- If $X$ is a random variable who's values are in $\mathbb{N}$, then $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \Sigma_{n≥0}\mathbb{P} (X > n)$$
- If $X$ is a random variable and $\mathbb{E}(X)$ exists, then the variance of X is: $$Var(X) = \mathbb{E}\Big((X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2\Big)$$

Now here are the examples I'd like to understand:

1. *binomial distribution*: If $X$ is a random variable that follows a binomial distribution of parametres $n$ and $p$ then we can write $X = X_1+X_2+X_3+...+X_n$ where the $X_i$'s are bernoulli variables of parametre $p$. Then $$Var(X) = np(1-p)$$
2. *negative binomial distribution (Pascal law)*: If X is a random variable that follows a pascal law of parameters $r$ and $p$ the $X+r= X_1+...+X_r$ where $X_i$'s are independant geometric variables. Then $$Var(X)=Var(X+r) = r\dfrac{1-p}{p^2}$$

I don't understand how one comes up with such results using the defintion of variance.

Comment: 1 ) By using $\text{Var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\text{Var}X_1+\cdots+\text{Var}X_n$. This is not true in general, but it is true if the $X_i$ are uncorrelated (wich is the case if they are independent). Secondly $Var{X_i}=p(1-p)$ for every $i$ (wich is easy to find) so the summation gives $np(1-p)$. Sortlike on 2) with the addition that $\text{Var}(X+r)=\text{Var}(X)$ if $r$ is a constant.

Comment: A useful formula for variance is $V (X)=E (X^2)-(E (X))^2$

Comment: Showing that the above formula is equivalent to the definition of variance is a good exercise, as well.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is **Bernoulli**, with $P(\text{Success}) = p,$ then $E(X) = (0)(1-p) + 1p = p.$ Because $0^2 = 0$ and $1^2 = 1$, we also have $E(X^2) = p.$
From @Dave's hint $Var(X) = p - p^2 = p(1-p).$

**Binomial:** Then for $Y \sim Binom(n, p),$ we have 
$$E(Y) = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = np.$$

Also, direct proofs, with 
$$E(Y) = \sum_{i=0}^n i{n \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} = \sum_{i=1}^n i{n \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} = \cdots = np(1) = np,$$ (with a change in index $j = i-1$) 
are given in many elementary texts.

Similarly, using independence,
$$Var(Y) = Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) = np(1-p).$$

Again here, proofs using about the same method as above to find $E(Y(Y-1)),$ and then
$Var(Y)$ from that and $E(Y),$ are given in many elementary texts.

For the **negative binomial**, it seems intuitive that the avarage waiting time
for the $r$th Success should be $r/p.$ A rigorous derivation of the expectation
of a negative binomial random variable often uses some sort of trick involving
differentiation of a sum. Probably the easiest route is to find the moment generating
function and differentiate it to get the mean and variance.

*Note:* You may find
some useful details on Wikipedia 'negative binomial distribution'. But if you
are looking at various references on negative binomial, be aware that
some parameterizations count *trials* until the $r$th Success and others count
only the *Failures* before the $r$th Success.